# Checking if the return of a method is List<String> with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to get the return type of a method using reflection, however I don't seem to be able to check for `List<String>` specifically.
I did it in a very *hacky* way:

```
if (method.getGenericReturnType().getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("java.util.List<java.lang.String>"))
```

Which isn't really what I should be doing, so I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: Did you try to debug what actually `method.getGenericReturnType().getTypeName()` returns?

Comment: @KhairulIslam It returns exactly what is in the string of the equals method, I was just wondering if there is a better way to checking it without needing to compare strings like this.

Comment: Can't you iterate over the List entries and compare the data type using instanceof?

Comment: @GarrenFitzenreiter then you would need to do this on each use of method and be sure to copy data to not allow any mutable state, as something could add different type to this list later. That would not be good solution when the type is available and OP just does not know how to use it. As type check could be made only once when app is starting, as type of method should not change in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`method.getGenericReturnType()` returns [java.lang.reflect.Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) and as you can see in javadocs it have a list of known subtypes:

```
All Known Subinterfaces:
GenericArrayType, ParameterizedType, TypeVariable<D>, WildcardType
```

So you can use that to perform few instanceof checks:

```
// is it ParameterizedType - so any type like Type<GenericType, OrMoreTypes>
if (!(method.getGenericReturnType() instanceof ParameterizedType)) return false;
ParameterizedType parametrizedReturnType = (ParameterizedType) method.getGenericReturnType();
// raw type is just a class without generic part
if (parametrizedReturnType.getRawType() != List.class) return false;
if (parametrizedReturnType.getActualTypeArguments().length != 1) return false;
Type firstArg = parametrizedReturnType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
return firstArg == String.class;
```

Note that type might be more complicated, yet still compatible with List if you just want to read some data, like method might have signature like `ArrayList<? extends String>` and then the check will return false. If you want also support such cases its best to use some libraries, like [org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.TypeUtils.isAssignable](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/TypeUtils.html#isAssignable-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.reflect.Type-) as such libraries allow you to create instance of Type definition (these libraries just have own implementations of these interfaces) and perform more advanced checks like `isAssignable` or `isInstance`, as sadly java does not provide such API.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I simply wanted to ignore a method if it was not returning exactly `List<String>`. I didn't know about `ParameterizedType` so best I could think of the string check. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, what if instead of String, I wnat to compare with Bar or any of its subclasses?

Comment: @ntg Not sure what you mean, can you add example? But look at `Class::isInstanceOf` and `Class::isAssignableFrom`

Comment: Thanx that should do it: `firstArg.getClass().isInstance(Bar.class)`

Comment: @ntg if you have a class than use `isAssignableFrom` as your code is checking if `Bar.class` is instance of class of first argument, that will be only true if first argument type is something like `Class` itself or any of it subtypes.